# Best Version of Ubuntu to Download

Tags: 12.04, installation

I have a question about which Ubuntu I am installing. Please take a look at this image:

[image: this image]

to better understand my problem. Can someone help me determine which Ubuntu I am installing? I want to download the latest version, which is 12.04 or 12.10, but I am having difficulties installing Ubuntu 12.04 desktop from CD or USB.

Comment: You are installing ubuntu using windows installer. It is called wubi installer. It packs ubuntu inside windows, read more here https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide

Answer (score 0):

The image says that your are installing Ubuntu 11.10. Can you be more specific about what exactly your are having issues with when attempting to install Ubuntu 12.04? You can download Ubuntu 12.04 (Intel x86) from [here](http://releases.ubuntu.com/precise/ubuntu-12.04.2-desktop-i386.iso). Copying the iso file to a USB from that link, and then rebooting your computer and pressing `F12` should help you boot up into Ubuntu. If you need more help, feel free to look at tutorials such as [this one](http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-install-ubuntu-12-04-precise-pangolin#.Uf1WnlPf0Xw).